# Function call by timer in C DLL

Tags: python, c, dll, timer, callback

I have a C DLL which is used in python script. I want to call C function periodically by timer. The problem is that I want to have this timer in DLL.
Let's say in DLL 2 functions: **printHello()** and **startTimer()**. From python script I call **startTimer(1second)**, so **printHello()** should be called every 1 second when timer expires, while in parallel doing another stuff in python script.
Any hints, theory readings? I don't need code, just understand how it works.

Comment: Do you understand how this would be done in pure C? I don't see how the introduction of python would introduce any problems here.

Comment: Not really. I think it should be separate thread in DLL, is it?

Comment: That's how I would do it.